# Pickle Load Custom Object Parameters Misaligned

Tags: python, pickle

Car.py:

```
   class Car(object):
        def __init__(self, year=2023, speed=50):
            self.year = year 
            self.speed = speed
            self.word_index = {}
```

Util.py:

```
from custom.Car import Car
c1 = Car(2020, 40)
picklefile = open('car.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(c1, picklefile)
    
with open('car.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    c2 = Car(pickle.load(f))
```

After loading the file, the entire Car object is assigned to self.year. So I end up have:
c2.year: The serialized Car object.
c2.speed: default speed of 50 instead of 40.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the output of `pickle.load` as the first arg (i.e. `year`) to `Car`'s init method. You don't need to pass the output of loading your pickle file to `Car`'s  constructor. Just use `pickle.load`.

```py
with open('car.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    c2 = pickle.load(f)
```